# If $(2x^2-3x+1)(2x^2+5x+1)=9x^2$,then prove that the equation has real roots.

Tags: roots, quadratics

If $(2x^2-3x+1)(2x^2+5x+1)=9x^2$,then prove that the equation has real roots.

MY attempt:

We can open and get a bi quadratic but that is two difficult to show that it has real roots.THere must be an easy way.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First divide both members of the equation by $x^2$:

$$(2x + \frac{1}{x} - 3)(2x + \frac{1}{x} + 5) = 9$$

With the notation $2x + \frac{1}{x} = y$ equation is obtained in $y$: $$y^2 + 2y - 24 =0$$ with roots $y_1 = -6$ and $y_2=4$.

The equation $$2x + \frac{1}{x} = -6$$ has roots $x_1,_2 = \frac{-3\pm\sqrt{7}}{2}$;

The equation $$2x + \frac{1}{x} = 4$$ has roots $x_3,_4 = \frac{2\pm\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Note that if we set $$f(x)=(2x^2-3x+1)(2x^2+5x+1)-9x^2$$ then $$f(1)\times f(2)<0$$ Now use [Intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Comment: +1 Although I didn't get it

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: $f$ is continuous on $[1,2]$ and $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ have the opposite signs so there is a $c\in(1,2)$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Comment: I see that. But how about the other roots?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: Maybe the OP can change the intervals. I say this because the structure of the function is not that complicated than the OP couldn't examine other numbers.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi since one root is always guaranteed to exist in $(1,2)$, the other will be also real, because complex roots come in conjugates of each other.

Comment: @Babak Now got it

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay But the degree is four, finding one real guarantees one other real root. Two roots remain and they can be both real or both complex conjugate.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: If we want to go via this approach, I think the way Samarat suggested was preferable.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi you are right. But I just found that in this case, also $f(0)f(1)<0$

Comment: But @BabakS.  f(0)=1

Comment: You are doing very well! +1

Answer (score 4):

$$(2x^2-3x+1)(2x^2+5x+1)=(2x^2+x+1)^2-16x^2=9x^2\\\Rightarrow 2x^2+x+1=\pm5x\\ \Rightarrow 2x^2+ax+1=0 $$ where $a=-4\ \mbox{or}\ 6$. Hence the discriminant, $$\Delta=a^2-8>0$$ always. So the roots are real.